# Error during apt-get update

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, gnupg

While running `apt-get` i get the following error :-

```
W: GPG error: https://dl.bintray.com  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99E82A75642AC823
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samrog131/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/samrog131/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried a number of solutions each of which failed. I can't install any software using `sudo apt-get update` in their script now :(
I have already tried system updates, trying to contact the keyserver (which always returns a timeout)

Comment: Which solutions have you tried already? Mention them or you will only be offered them again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically running the following should work:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 99E82A75642AC823
 sudo apt-get update
```

In this case, I don't think this will work because:

1. There is no trusty packages for octave as you can see from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/)
2. User `samrog131` no longer maintains a PPA as you can see from [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Esamrog131)

It is better to remove these PPAs from your sources list. Read an excellent answer from  [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) to know how to do that.